# CruiseControl: Run from Command Line = Success, as Windows Service = Failure

Tags: ant, classpath, cruisecontrol

Really hope you can help. I've configured CruiseControl to build a java project on a spare Windows XP machine in the office, but am finding it errors out with a ClassDefNotFound when CruiseControl is invoked via a Windows Service.

The exact error is: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher`

I understand this to be in the ant-launcher.jar file.

I've placed this file (and all the other Ant 1.8.2 jars) in the lib subdirectory of CruiseControl. When run on the commandline from the CruiseControl directory with the following command, I don't get any classpath errors:

```
cruisecontrol --configfile config.xml
```

I'm really hoping this is either trivial to a fresh pair of eyes, or rings a bell with someone who's trodden this path before.

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: Wild guess- could it be just the user context? Try configuring your user as the running user (enter XP's services, right click->properties on CruiseControl.Net service, switch to log on tab and set a different user).

Answer (score 1):

Your environment variables are probably defined as user variables rather than system variables. Services will not be run as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke the cruisecontrol-launcher.jar file from your cruise control installation path & also ensure that cruise control process has been started as a service.

eg:-

```
java -jar C:\Program Files\CruiseControl\lib\cruisecontrol-launcher.jar
```